# Optimizing a GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Just trying to optimize a SQL Query.

```
SELECT   Code, COUNT(*) 
FROM     tblData 
WHERE    ListID = 380 
GROUP BY Code
```

The table contains 10 million records. So the query usually take 4-5 secs to find the record on SQL SERVER 2008 R2. I found another way of expressing it:

```
SELECT a.Code, COUNT(*) 
FROM   (  SELECT * 
          FROM   tblData 
          WHERE  ListID = 380 
       ) a 
GROUP BY a.Code
```

Though in my tests it produce the results in the exact same time. But I wonder if this is faster the previous one or visa versa. Any idea?

Comment: What do you have indexed and what does the query planner/analyzer tell you?

Comment: By the way, there's no such things as *SQL Server 2010*. Did you mean *SQL Server 2008 R2* (which was released in 2010)?

Comment: Yes i mean that. I actually get confuse with its version been 10.50..lol Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With any decent query optimizer, the two queries should boil down to the exact same operations. So I'm not surprised you find they run in the same time.

I don't think you can modify your query to make it run any faster. What you can do, of course, is to have an index on `ListID` - but I expect you have that already.

Comment: LISTID is primary key and hence already Index, I also create an Index on Code since it is grouped.  But I still want to optimize, as this is main table in our project.

Comment: It could be that an index on `(ListID, Code)`, as suggested by @Mitch, would help. Further than that, I don't see how to improve it. Unless you have very few `ListID` values, and you are willing to physically split `tblData` into several tables and query them independently, so that you would avoid the `where` clause (disclaimer: that's ugly!)

Comment: Okak, though I have a index on both field individually, but I create third index, for combination of Code and ListID. This optimize my query to take less than a second now.

Comment: @SumitGupta: If `ListID` is your primary key, won't you always get a single record returned in your query?

Comment: @Mitch was right, though he delete his reply. Thanks Mitch, and Cornuz, combine Index works for me.

Comment: @Sumit: Is `ListID` really the Primary Key of the table? Or just a part of a composite Primary Key?

Answer (score 3):

As @cornuz and @Wim both said, these two queries should be equivalent.

However, you may find that having a two-column index (on ListId then Code) would improve the performance quite a bit, because

1. the database would just visit the index, not the table; and
2. the index wouldn't have to do an extra sort, to bring together
   the rows that have to be counted together.

Answer (score 0):

In Management Studio, select both queries and click on "Display Estimated Execution Plan". As soon as one Query Cost differs from 50%, you have winner (and a looser).

Your second query looks as the result of the first query after it has passed the Analyser. I think both will perform exactly the same.